# PayPal Rest API Get Sale - REQUIRED_SCOPE_MISSING

Tags: paypal

Today I have been trying to implement the rest API into my application to look up transaction information from a transaction ID (GET /v1/payments/sale/)

I have implemented everything correctly on my end and set the mode to "live" and I can't seem to get details from a transaction.

Here is the full error code:

{"name":"REQUIRED_SCOPE_MISSING","message":"Access token does not have required scope","information_link":"https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#REQUIRED_SCOPE_MISSING"}

And here is documentation on what I am trying to do: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/#look-up-a-sale

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There are few things you could do to make sure your configurations are set right.

1. If the mode is set to live, are you using the live credentials instead of sandbox. You can select the sandbox app and copy the `live credentials` from there. See bottom part of this image.

[image]

2. Make sure Payments are enabled on live. PayPal has a dashboard page, where you could see all the services that you have enabled to work with Live environment. This prevents accidents on unknowingly using an API on live. You can check the status [here](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/account/status)

[image]

3. Is the sale that you are looking for created by the same clientId that you are using for making a GET call ? Only the app who creates the sale, can view the sale.
4. In the mean time, PayPal has created [SDKs](https://github.com/paypal?query=PayPal-) for many languages to support REST APIs. They are actively developed, and maintained, and could help you mitigate issues in handling tokens, credentials, etc, and allows you to quickly use APIs faster and in a way that could be upgraded easily. Also, few SDKs come packaged with Sample codes, and wiki documentations. Few are still under development, but you can feel free to contribute back to these open source SDKs.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer, I am currently using the PayPal SDK for .net.

I am afraid I may not be looking for a "sale" I am looking for the status of a general transaction.

so instead of the id being formatted like PAY-XXXX.* just XXXX, I am simply trying to lookup the status of a transaction from the API, and I am unsure how to do that, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @VirdianX your question shows that what you're looking for is a `sale` resource.  The `id` for the `sale` resource is the **transaction ID** that shows up in your merchant dashboard.  The way you search for this ID using the REST API is by first getting a [list of payment resources](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/#list-payment-resources), and then looking at the `related_resources` property of each payment to see if it contains a `sale` resource whose `id` matches that **transaction ID**.

Comment: I should also add that searching the payments is only necessary if you don't know what type of transaction resource is associated with the **transaction ID** (e.g. it could be a `sale`, `refund`, `capture`, `authorization`, etc. resource).  If you know for a fact that it's a `sale` resource, then what you're doing is correct - it simply looks like it's an issue with the credentials you're using with the SDK (which Jay has provided a helpful answer for above)

Comment: Hi,

Thanks for the reply, but I don't think getting the payment history will work for what I am needing to do, let me describe the situation further, I am migrating 2 systems together, and the user needs to provide a valid transaction ID to authenticate that they have purchased the product previously, to do that I need to directly lookup the transaction ID.

Answer (score 0):

When I had this issue, the problem was that I was making REST requests using the Identity API token. Basically, I was logging users into my website with Paypal then using that token for REST requests when another token from the REST API service should have been used. "

Here is the support ticket from Paypal SDK deveoper Randy who helped answer my question even though I do not use the SDK. Thanks Randy:

https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK/issues/785#issuecomment-282749095